# What's the deal with the Witcher 2 DLC?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So my game informed me today that a new patch (1.2) was available for The Witcher 2, and among the patch notes were the following:

> All previously released DLC packages
>   are installed with Patch 1.2:
>
> - "Blue Stripes Combat Jacket"
> - "Ultimate Alchemist's Outfit"
> - "Ultimate Mage's Outfit"
> - "Ultimate Swordsman's Outfit"
> - "Finisher Pack"
> - "Mysterious Merchant"
> - "Troll Trouble"

Of these, the only one I'd heard about was "Troll Trouble". Where are the other DLC items that are mentioned in the patch notes? What do they contain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Blue Stripes Combat Jacket:** Chestpiece item. Added to inventory following the prologue.

**Ultimate Alchemy Outfit:** A few alchemical items and gauntlets only. Added to inventory following prologue.

**Ultimate Mage's Outfit:** A trouser item. Added to inventory following prologue.

**Ultimate Swordsman's Outfit:** A collection of oils, potions and whetstones that aid with swordplay. Added to inventory following prologue.

**Finisher Pack:** Automatic, adds new finisher animations.

**Mysterious Merchant:** In Flotsam, he was on the porch on the left if looking towards the town from where you entered originally. He sold an improved silversword and some other stuff.

**Troll Trouble:** In Lobinden (village outside Flotsam), find a guy named "Chorab" to get a new quest.

[There is additionally a new piece of DLC](http://www.en.thewitcher.com/patch1-2/):

> #### "Barbers and Coiffeuses"
>
> Some traders also provide barbershop services. For a small fee, Geralt can get them to change his hairstyle. Search notice boards for information about barbers and coiffeuses offering services of this nature in a given location. In Flotsam, in Chapter 1 of the game, these services are available from the antique book dealer Einar Gausel. In Chapter 2, look either for Sambor in Henselt’s Camp or for Felicia Cori in Vergen. This apprentice sorceress also provides hairstyling services in Loc Muinne, in Chapter 3 of the game.

Comment: One update: the Armor pieces / blade oils / potions / whetstones are available *during* the prologue. (Though obviously not through the dungeons).